# Why is Java Optional type information lost?

Tags: java, option-type, type-inference

I have these classes with the method:

```
public abstract class Bar<T extends Bar> {
    Foo myFoo;
    public Optional<Foo> findFoo() { return Optional.ofNullable(this.myFoo); }
}

public class Baz extends Bar<Baz> {
}
```

, where Foo is a concrete final class and o is an object that extends Bar.

It ok to get the value in my unit test this way:

```
Bar bar = new Baz();
Optional<Foo> optinalFoo =  bar.findFoo();
Foo foo = optionalFoo.get();
```

However, when called directly the type information is lost:

```
Foo foo = bar.findFoo().get();
```

In the second example the compiler thinks get() returns an Object instead of a Foo. Why? Is there a way to provide the type information to the compiler in some other way?

(I know that you should avoid calling get() directly but since this is in a unit test it's ok if it throws on unexpected results.)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Specifically: what is **o** ?

Comment: Is `Foo` a generic type or a concrete one? Having "some class with a method" is not descriptive enough for us to understand the issue or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it won't compile due to `return.ofNullable`. what does it mean?

Comment: Works for me, what exactly is `o`?

Comment: I have updated the example for completeness. The key seems to be related to the generic inheritance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bar` variable uses raw type, so it lacks all generic type checks. Defining type `Optional<Foo> optionalFoo` you also have unchecked assignment (it means types will be checked run-time only), but compiler sees the type and the `.get()` works fine. To fix you need to define generic parameter, e.g.

```
Bar<? extends Bar> bar = new Baz();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bar bar` is a raw type. Raw types don't have any generic information, it's an all or nothing thing. There isn't a nice, kind of generic fall back.  An example is

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = map.entrySet();

// however when you use a raw type there is no generic.
Map map2 = new HashMap();
Set<Map.Entry> entries2 = map2.entrySet(); // doesn't work
Set entries2 = map2.entrySet(); // does work
```

This is because raw types are provided for backward compatibility only.  In versions before Java 5.0 there was no generic and so you had to expect raw type didn't have any generics.